# Run perl file from plesk's scheduled tasks every minute

Tags: perl

Can anyone please tell how to run perl file from plesk's scheduled tasks every minute... There are plenty of tutorials for php files but can't find anything useful for perl...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never actually used the scheduled tasks feature of plesk but it looks like it just sets up a standard cron job. I entered the following info and it looks to have worked out.

Choose the user you want the script to run as and then give it the following information.

```
Minuet = */1
Hour = * 
Day of Month = *
Month = *
Day of week = *
command = /absolute/path/to/yourscript.pl
```

Really it should be identical to any PHP tutorial you just point the command at your perl script instead. Make sure your script is executable and starts with the proper #!/usr/bin/perl path.

Answer (score -2):

for the command : 
perl /absolute/path/to/file.pl

Comment: This would need a lot more of explanation.